# thrift nodejs client and php server works together?

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, rpc, thrift

I plan to use nodejs as the client, and php as the server. I use the official [tutorial.thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/).

I set up a nginx server to host the `localhost:9099` with the dir `/path/to/my/tutorial/`, generate a server script as index.php and place it in the root ,when visit the `localhost:9099`,so that client visit the server through `index.php`.
the `index.php` content:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once __DIR__ . "/Thrift/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php";
use Thrift\ClassLoader\ThriftClassLoader;

$ROOT = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$GEN_DIR = $ROOT.'/gen-php';

$loader = new ThriftClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Thrift', $ROOT);
$loader->registerNamespace('Swoole', $ROOT);
$loader->registerNamespace('tutorial', $GEN_DIR);
$loader->registerDefinition('shared', $GEN_DIR);
$loader->registerDefinition('tutorial', $GEN_DIR);
$loader->register();

if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    ini_set("display_errors", "stderr");
}

use Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol;
use Thrift\Transport\TPhpStream;
use Thrift\Transport\TBufferedTransport;
use Thrift\Server\TServer;

header('Content-Type', 'application/x-thrift');
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    echo "\r\n";
}

$handler = new \tutorial\Handler();
$processor = new \tutorial\CalculatorProcessor($handler);

$transport = new TBufferedTransport(new TPhpStream(TPhpStream::MODE_R | TPhpStream::MODE_W));
$protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport, true, true);

$transport->open();
$processor->process($protocol, $protocol);
$transport->close();
```

the `client.node.js` content:

```
/**
 * Created by Kron on 16/4/12.
 */
var thrift = require('thrift');
var ThriftTransports = require('thrift/transport');
var ThriftProtocols = require('thrift/protocol');
var Calculator = require('../gen-nodejs/Calculator');
var ttypes = require('../gen-nodejs/tutorial_types');

transport = ThriftTransports.TBufferedTransport();
protocol = ThriftProtocols.TBinaryProtocol();


var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 9099, {
    transport : transport,
    protocol : protocol
});

var client = thrift.createClient(Calculator, connection);


connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    //assert(false, err);
});

// Create a Calculator client with the connection

client.ping(function(err, response) {
    console.log('ping()');
});

client.add(1,1, function(err, response) {
    console.log("1+1=" + response);
});

work = new ttypes.Work();
work.op = ttypes.Operation.DIVIDE;
work.num1 = 1;
work.num2 = 0;

client.calculate(1, work, function(err, message) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("InvalidOperation " + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Whoa? You know how to divide by zero?');
    }
});

work.op = ttypes.Operation.SUBTRACT;
work.num1 = 15;
work.num2 = 10;

client.calculate(1, work, function(err, message) {
    console.log('15-10=' + message);

    client.getStruct(1, function(err, message){
        console.log('Check log: ' + message.value);

        //close the connection once we're done
        connection.end();
    });
});
```

The `client.php` content:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once __DIR__ . "/../Thrift/ClassLoader/ThriftClassLoader.php";
use Thrift\ClassLoader\ThriftClassLoader;

$ROOT = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../');
$GEN_DIR = $ROOT.'/gen-php';

$loader = new ThriftClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Thrift', $ROOT);
$loader->registerNamespace('Swoole', $ROOT);
$loader->registerNamespace('tutorial', $GEN_DIR);
$loader->registerDefinition('shared', $GEN_DIR);
$loader->registerDefinition('tutorial', $GEN_DIR);
$loader->register();

use Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol;
use Thrift\Transport\TSocket;
use Thrift\Transport\THttpClient;
use Thrift\Transport\TBufferedTransport;
use Thrift\Exception\TException;

try {
    if (array_search('--http', $argv)) {
        $socket = new THttpClient('localhost', 9099, '/clients_servers/tutorial.server.php');
    } else {
        $socket = new THttpClient('localhost', 9099); // 8080 for node server, 9099 for php server
    }

    $transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
    $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
    $client = new \tutorial\CalculatorClient($protocol);

    $transport->open();

    $client->ping();
    print "ping()\n";

    $sum = $client->add(1,1);
    print "1+1=$sum\n";

    $work = new \tutorial\Work();

    $work->op = \tutorial\Operation::DIVIDE;
    $work->num1 = 1;
    $work->num2 = 0;

    try {
        $client->calculate(1, $work);
        print "Whoa! We can divide by zero?\n";
    } catch (\tutorial\InvalidOperation $io) {
        print "InvalidOperation: $io->why\n";
    }

    $work->op = \tutorial\Operation::SUBTRACT;
    $work->num1 = 15;
    $work->num2 = 10;
    $diff = $client->calculate(1, $work);
    print "15-10=$diff\n";

    $log = $client->getStruct(1);
    print "Log: $log->value\n";

    $transport->close();

} catch (TException $tx) {
    print 'TException: '.$tx->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

They're almost the same as original.

1. when I use `client.php` visit the host, It works well.
2. when I use `client.node.js` visit the host, It doesn't work.
3. when I try to use a node server,*not the host*, visit it use the `client.php`,I have to change `$socket = new THttpClient('localhost', 9099)` to `$socket = new TSocket('localhost', 9099)` to make it work.
4. `client.node.js` never ever touched the `localhost:9099`, and without any stdout.

Comment: Thanks @JensG for removing useless words~

Comment: That's a general policy on SO (and SE in general). Personal help cries and greetings do not match the intended Q&A format very well. So it's not about you personally.

Answer (score 1):

Finally my partner helped me found the answer.

the official demo of nodejs cient has some problems:

official code:

```
transport = ThriftTransports.TFramedTransport();
protocol = ThriftProtocols.TBinaryProtocol();
```

our code:

```
transport = ThriftTransports.TFramedTransport;
protocol = ThriftProtocols.TBinaryProtocol;
```

remove the `()`, that makes the code work.

Comment: Great - please consider supplying a [patch or pull request!](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute)

Answer (score 0):

[hbase-dir]/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift -f

I am facing same error. Refer http://dailyjs.com/post/hbase 
TFramedTransport is disable by default. You have to enable it by using above command.
Note : After enable you can't able to connect php. I AM using different protocols for that in php

Check this : 
[NodeJS Hbase thrift weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415528/nodejs-hbase-thrift-weirdness)